# Error in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm learning stored procedures and here is the code that i have written. But its giving error.

> Error: Incorrect syntax near '@return'.

My code:

```
create procedure test (@status varchar(50), @return varchar(50) output)
as
begin
    if @status = 'running'
        begin
            @return = '1'
        end
    else
        begin
            @return = '2'
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be

SET @return='1'

the rest is fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually use `SET` or `SELECT` to assign values:

```
create procedure test (@status varchar(50), @return varchar(50) output)
as
begin
    if @status = 'running'
       SET @return = '1'
    else
       SET @return = '2'
end
```